# javascript checkboxes: use a button to change a group to checked

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I've been using this (and it works/worked) with a regular web page, but when I try to attach Jquery (v1.9.1 + jquery mobile v 1.2.0 -- for button styling and other functionality) it seems to select the right objects (ran a console.log to see what item was being grabbed in the array) but it doesn't update the checkbox in the page (make it checked) despite returning a value of "true". It also does the same thing when I just do the basics in my jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/artcase_1/6sasA/2/

```
function checkUncheck(name, setTo) {


    var c = document.getElementsByName(name);

    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {

        if (c[i].type == 'checkbox' || c[i].checked == 'false') {

            c[i].checked = setTo;
        }
    }
}

<!-- in the body: -->
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <legend>choose a level to view</legend>
        <input name="colors" type="checkbox" class="custom"
        id="redbtn" value="red" checked="checked" />
        <label for="redbtn">High</label>
        <input name="colors" type="checkbox" class="custom" id="yellowbtn"
        value="yellow" />
        <label for="yellowbtn">Med</label>
        <input name="colors" type="checkbox" class="custom" id="bluebtn"
        value="blue" />
        <label for="bluebtn">Low</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<input name="Show_all_btn" type="button" id="showall" onclick="checkUncheck('colors','true')"
value="check all" />
```

Comment: You've just set it up wrong in the Fiddle, change onLoad, to nowrap-body and it works -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6sasA/4/)

Comment: What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend separating your javascript from your HTML so this would be your updated js would be something like this:

```
var check_all = document.getElementById('showall');

function checkUncheck(name, setTo) {


var c = document.getElementsByName(name);

for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {

    if (c[i].type == 'checkbox' || c[i].checked == 'false') {

        c[i].checked = setTo;
    }
}

}
check_all.addEventListener('click', checkUncheck.bind(null, 'colors', true), false);
```

Here's a demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sasA/5/)

Comment: I've never used bind before, from your code example above, it seems to add an initial variable to the callback set, right (0: null, 1:"color", 2: true) or am I missing something?

Comment: -- also, checkUncheck is called inside another function that does more, it's not the only thing that happens when the user clicks. So I'm not sure how I can bind it to the click event listener. Is it okay to add multiple functions to something like that? (I'm new, and coming from a graphic arts background so please forgive...)